# Thunderbird stops sending email

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Thunderbird 14
I have configured correctly all accounts using common Local folders
I send and receive correctly emails.
Suddenly, usually 4-5 hours after I switch the pc on, I can not send email but receive only.
Other information is that it is a dual boot pc with Vista and both OS are using same profile folder.

Comment: Do you get any sort of error popup when a mail fails to send?

Comment: yes, standard email smtp server failure dialog box. some times sending stops at 88%, other times in less

Comment: one day before the first day I noticed it, I have installed only cifs-utils. And also I remember I had at the same time problems in Firefox (saving web forms). I do not know if they are related however. strange?

Comment: it happened again, after 4-5h since last power on (it is reproducible).

Comment: Sending of message failed.
The message could not be sent because the connection to SMTP server mail.xx.yy timed out. Try again or contact your network administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I found out is generated every time `dmesg.log` is updated. Solution is to reset wireless connection. It is generally not only Thunderbird but sending out network connection problem.