# 12.04 Wi-Fi not working correctly with Intel Pro/Wireless 3945ABG

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

This is a very strange problem. The only time the Wi-Fi works is when I have the wired connection connected. I have a Dell 6400/e1505 with the Broadcom BCM 4401-B0 internal NIC, and the Intel Pro/Wireless 3945ABG Wi-Fi adapter.

I was on 10.0.4 LTS before, and I remember having to screw around to get the Wi-Fi to work, but that was years ago, and now it's acting even stranger than it did back then.

If I boot up with the wire connected, the Wi-Fi starts up. If I boot up without the wire connected, the Wi-Fi won't start at all. If after booting with the wire connected, and the Wi-Fi starts up, I then disable the wireless, the wired connection works fine.

Without the wire connected, `dmesg` shows the iwl3945 driver loading and starting with no errors, and the wireless adapter activated. Running `rfkill list` shows no blocks, but there is no connection to my Wi-Fi.

Help! I am more confused than a chameleon in a bag of Skittles.

Comment: What if you start with wired and wifi, and then remove the ethernet cable, and disable / re-enable wireless?

Comment: The problem is booting without the wire connected, which is what I want to be able to do. I need wifi! It's totally bogus that connecting the WIRE is the only way to get WIRELESS to work!

Comment: Oh, and btw, that does work fine. Doing what you said works fine. It does not, however, allow the wireless to work if I boot without the wire connected.

Comment: I had also similar problem in the past, the reason is unknown... see http://askubuntu.com/questions/171498/thunderbird-stops-sending-email

Comment: Ok, I found the answer [here](http://www.necopost.com/2012/06/network-manager-not-running-error-on.html). Turns out network-manager was not able to control the interface during startup. The solution is to edit /etc/network/interfaces and remove all the extra lines after "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback" and reboot. Now I just have to figure out how to make the wifi LED stop blinking 100% of the time.

Comment: I also had to add a configuration file for my wireless adaptor to the modprobe.d directory. It had two lines: alias wlan0 iwl3945 and the second was options iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=1

Comment: did you do a compare of syslog with and without the wired network connected? What was the difference? If yes, maybe that is what you need to resolve first.

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04, there is a `iwl_legacy` kernel module options that governs the blinking. To stop the blinking, add another file to /etc/modprobe.d/ with the following content - `iwl_legacy=1`.

**step by step**

1. Run `gksudo gedit /etc/moprobe.d/iwl_legacy.conf`
2. Copy/paste `iwl_legacy` into the file.
3. Save and exit.

The wifi led shouldn't blink after a reboot.